# how to show radchartview custom tooltips for all series between two Y ages Point

Tags: telerik

i want to display custom tooltip without using trackball.
my requirement is to show tooltips for dynamically added Series which is live trend data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFzsO.png)

I want to display round marked series point X value in tooltips.
I am using RadChartView control of telerik with VS2017.